# Targeting strings in a listview android

Tags: java, android, list, listview

```
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {


                if(position == 1 ){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Click ListItem Number " + position,
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
                }else{
                     }
```

i  have a list view from a custom adapter that works fine and when i click an item it gets the correct position.
how can i exract a field views text out of the position. ie

```
 holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
```

i want to target the desc field out of the position listem that i clicked.. 
i know you can use hash mapping but is there a way to just target a field view on item click by its list position?  I know this is "webby" but I am sure java has the same flexibility

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());


    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can i exract a field views text out of the position. ie
>
> ```
> holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
> ```

Inside `onItemClick()` you can use:

```
TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
// Now use textView.getText().toString() to get the description
```

Since `convertView` from the Adapter is the same object as `view` in the Listener.

Comment: This will work, but grabbing the data back out of the presentation layer is sub-optimal, and won't work when you aren't listing a simple array of Strings.

Comment: "grabbing the data back out of the presentation layer is sub-optimal" Yup, but only by milliseconds, I posted two alternates in the comments below your question. "and won't work when you aren't listing a simple array of Strings" The question is about displaying Strings.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to leave that there in case someone else comes across this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just call `adapter.getItem(position)`?

Comment: wont all that do is get the position in the list?

Comment: Are you using an ArrayAdapter to put an array of Objects into your listView? If so, then you can call yourAdapter.getItem(position), where position is the argument that camein on the click handler function. This will give you the original Object you passed in to the adapter.

Comment: yes I am listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString(); i was trying this but I need just a specific section not the whole text

Comment: That's only part of the question. Are you using an ArrayAdapter?

Comment: yes i made a custom one because i have a few lines of text so i am converting textviews

Comment: @Dnaso This solution can also work, but we'll need to know what objects are being displayed in the Adapter.  In other words, post `getView()` in you question.

Comment: Inside `onItemClick()` you can use: `((RowItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(i)).getDesc()` _or_ `adapter.getItem(position).getDesc()`. (You might need to cast the second example to a RowItem depending on your Adapter.)

Comment: im not even sure why though, considering it doesnt get the "position" first unless it already assumes its the one you are clicking.

Comment: @Dnaso `view` is the row that you clicked, so you don't need to worry about the `position` in my answer.

Comment: oh ok i get it.. sorry new to android.. i have a web background thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need only text current item use BaseAdapter and you can get text following way:

   (String) adapter.getItem(position);
2. If you need TextView object current item you can get TextView following way:
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view;
           TextView txtDescTV = holder.txtDesc;
       }
   }